# Cordova/Phonegap Show option to use either camera or gallery

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, sencha-touch

My basic need is to upload an image to the server. The image can be taken using the camera or from the gallery.
I know that by changing the source type I can set the source from which the image is to be taken.

```
Camera.PictureSourceType = {
  PHOTOLIBRARY : 0,
  CAMERA : 1,
  SAVEDPHOTOALBUM : 2
};
```

This is working perfectly for me. 
But I want to give the user an option to select the source type  (camera or gallery) upon clicking a button. This is how it is implemented in many apps.  I don't want two separate buttons for camera and gallery.

I am running this on android device and I am using cordova with sencha-touch.

Comment: That can't be done on android, you have to show your own html message with your own buttons to let the user choose and then change the PictureSourceType accordingly